# Node.js TCP write multiple commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I am connecting to a serial device over the internet, using an ethernet to serial device. I am communicating with it via a small node.js app. The following code gets back the information I need:

```
var net = require('net');

var zone1 = 'AgABBgAJ';
var zone2 = 'AgACBgAK';
var zone3 = 'AgACBfAZ';
var zone4 = 'AgACBaAW';
var zone5 = 'AgACBsAV';

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(10006, '10.0.1.217', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write(Buffer.from(zone1, 'base64').toString('ascii')+'\n');

});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    var data_array = new Uint8Array(data);
    console.log(data_array);
    var decoded = [];
    decoded['zone'] = data_array[16];
    decoded['power'] = data_array[18] == 128 ? 'On' : data_array[18] == 0 ? 'Off' : data_array[18] == 192 ? 'Muted' : 'Unknown';
    decoded['input'] = data_array[22] + 1;
    decoded['vol'] = data_array[23] - 196;
    decoded['mute'] = data_array[18] == 192 ? 'On' : 'Off';
    decoded['state'] = (data_array[18] == 128) || (data_array[18] == 192) ? true : false;

    console.log('-- Zone: ' + decoded['zone']);
    console.log('-- Power: ' + decoded['power']);
    console.log('-- Input: ' + decoded['input']);
    console.log('-- Volume: ' + decoded['vol']);
    console.log('-- Mute: ' + decoded['mute']);

    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

What I need to do now is write the other commands (zone2,zone3,zone4,zone5) and get the data back from them as well.

Is there a way to loop through an array of commands and output the data after each command?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the output from the app

```
Connected
Uint8Array [
  2, 0, 0,   6, 0, 63, 0,   0,
  0, 0, 0,   0, 0, 71, 2,   0,
  1, 5, 0,   0, 0,  0, 0, 222,
  8, 8, 0, 246
]
-- Zone: 1
-- Power: Off
-- Input: 1
-- Volume: 26
-- Mute: Off
Connection closed
```

Comment: Are you saying that you need to send a command, wait for the response, then send the next one and so on?

Comment: @jfriend00 exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create yourself a little state machine where you put the zones in an array and keep a variable that points to the next index in that array to process.  Then, after you finish processing the `data` event for a zone, you send the command for the next zone until you have no more items in the array.

```
const net = require('net');

const zones = [
    'AgABBgAJ',
    'AgACBgAK',
    'AgACBfAZ',
    'AgACBaAW',
    'AgACBsAV'
];

let zoneIndex = 0;
const client = new net.Socket();

function sendNextZone() {
    if (zoneIndex < zones.length) {
        client.write(Buffer.from(zones[zoneIndex++], 'base64').toString('ascii')+'\n');
    } else {
        // no more zones to send,  so we're done
        client.destroy();
    }
}


client.connect(10006, '10.0.1.217', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    sendNextZone();    
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    let data_array = new Uint8Array(data);
    console.log(data_array);
    let decoded = [];
    decoded['zone'] = data_array[16];
    decoded['power'] = data_array[18] == 128 ? 'On' : data_array[18] == 0 ? 'Off' : data_array[18] == 192 ? 'Muted' : 'Unknown';
    decoded['input'] = data_array[22] + 1;
    decoded['vol'] = data_array[23] - 196;
    decoded['mute'] = data_array[18] == 192 ? 'On' : 'Off';
    decoded['state'] = (data_array[18] == 128) || (data_array[18] == 192) ? true : false;

    console.log('-- Zone: ' + decoded['zone']);
    console.log('-- Power: ' + decoded['power']);
    console.log('-- Input: ' + decoded['input']);
    console.log('-- Volume: ' + decoded['vol']);
    console.log('-- Mute: ' + decoded['mute']);

    // done processing this zone, send the command for the next one
    sendNextZone();
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

Note: There is no complete guarantee with a TCP socket that you will get all the data you want in one `data` event - it is possible, particularly with larger data sets or slower networks that the data might be split between multiple `data` events.  If that were the case, you would need a buffer so you could buffer data until you had a "full" set of data that you could then process.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Array or Set for your zones.

```
const zones = [
  'AgABBgAJ',
  'AgACBgAK',
  'AgACBfAZ',
  'AgACBaAW',
  'AgACBsAV'
];
```

Then, you can loop through easily:

```
for (const zone of zones) {
  client.write(Buffer.from(zone, 'base64').toString('ascii') + '\n');
  // etc.
}
```

However, there's probably more you need to do here.  I would recommend building out a small client class that can wrap up your commands and status retrieval.  I assume you want to get a response before querying the next zone, rather than fire-and-forget.  Check out [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: thanks, I have tried this before though and I only ever get the data from the first value in the array..

Comment: @Chad Right, as I mentioned, you'll probably want to wait for a response before hitting the next.  You're going to have to handle buffering the response data and parsing.  I also wouldn't assume the response fits in one packet... but I don't know your protocol so you would know better on that.

Comment: hmm, I have never really built anything around a connection like this before, I am not really sure where to begin for buffering the response data. any suggestions?

Comment: What I usually do is keep an array of buffers as they come in.  Once the length of the buffers adds up to the size of a message I'm expecting, I concatenate or copy the data from those original buffers to a message buffer for decoding.  I then call some function to parse whatever messages are in the queue.  Depending on the application, I'll either do this directly in the handler for when data arrives, or I'll write a TransformStream that emits objects.  Then, I can pipe the socket directly to the stream.

Comment: In any case, I would create an async function for `queryStatus()` or something.  That function will emit the data needed to get the status, and when it receives a status corresponding to the ID that was sent, it will resolve its promise.  (Don't forget to reject the promise on timeout or socket error as well!)